# How do I convert an object to an array?

Tags: php

```
<?php
   print_r($response->response->docs);
?>
```

Outputs the following:

```
    Array 
(
    [0] => Object 
            (
                [_fields:private] => Array 
                                    (
                                        [id]=>9093 
                                        [name]=>zahir
                                    ) 
            Object 
            ( 
                [_fields:private] => Array 
                                    (
                                        [id]=>9094 
                                        [name]=>hussain
                                    )..
            )
)
```

How can I convert this object to an array?  I'd like to output the following:

```
Array
(
    [0]=>
    (
        [id]=>9093 
        [name]=>zahir
    ) 
    [1]=>
    (
        [id]=>9094 
        [name]=>hussain
    )...
)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You should look at [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/function.get-object-vars.php) , as your properties are declared private you should call this inside the class and return its results.

Be careful, for primitive data types like strings it will  work great, but I don't know how it behaves with nested objects.

in your case you have to do something like;

```
<?php
   print_r(get_object_vars($response->response->docs));
?>
```

Answer (score 394):

### Single-dimensional arrays

For converting single-dimension arrays, you can cast using `(array)` or there's [`get_object_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php), which Benoit mentioned in 
[his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2477159/94197).

```
// Cast to an array
$array = (array) $object;
```

```
// get_object_vars
$array = get_object_vars($object);
```

They work slightly different from each other.  For example, `get_object_vars` will return an array with only publicly accessible properties unless it is called from within the scope of the object you're passing (ie in a member function of the object).  `(array)`, on the other hand, will cast to an array with all public, private and protected members intact on the array, though all public now, of course.

### Multi-dimensional arrays

A somewhat dirty method is to use PHP >= 5.2's native JSON functions to encode to JSON and then decode back to an array.  This will not include private and protected members, however, and is not suitable for objects that contain data that cannot be JSON encoded (such as binary data).

```
// The second parameter of json_decode forces parsing into an associative array
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
```

Alternatively, the following function will convert from an object to an array including private and protected members, taken from [here](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-Object-To-Array-With-PHP.html) and modified to use casting:

```
function objectToArray ($object) {
    if(!is_object($object) && !is_array($object))
        return $object;

    return array_map('objectToArray', (array) $object);
}
```

Comment: First solution didn't handle mutlidimensions, but second solution worked great.

Comment: 2nd solution reminded me there is a 2nd parameter to json_decode() which I forgot.. thanks.

Comment: I wonder why this answer is getting so many votes. Both solutions are less clear and pretty than get_object_vars

Comment: @RJD22: I've updated my answer to make it more of a 'de facto' resource, hopefully you regard it as worthy of its up votes now. ;-)  Note to everyone else that the "2nd solution" the comments refer to here is the JSON solution, which was the 2nd in my first answer.

Comment: AWESOME! I was amazed by a solution and scrolled down to find this!

Comment: @RJD22 get_object_vars will not include private members, whereas casting to array will (with a strange class prefix).  Depending on your use case, they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 45):

You can quickly convert deeply nested objects to associative arrays by relying on the behavior of the JSON encode/decode functions:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($response->response->docs), true);
```

Comment: This is the most simple answer to this problem. Used it and it worked awesome. Thanks

Comment: Just a note - this will work in case your array contains UTF8 valid data. If your array contains some other encoding, let say Win1250, it will fail, as json_encode will fail (php 5.3)

Comment: How to convert it back to an object?

Comment: @Trix use json again json_decode(json_encode($array), FALSE);This also (recursively) converts all of your sub arrays into objects,

Comment: I wish I could uptick this more than once.

Comment: @galdikas sure. As you can see both [`json_encode()` (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PECL json >= 1.2.0, **PHP 7**)](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode()` (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PECL json >= 1.2.0, **PHP 7**)](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) are supported in PHP7.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I am using it for Drupal/Apache Solr

Comment: But if you have BINARY data, let's said... an object that contain a binary. Then this snippet will brake the code giving you a null object

Answer (score 34):

Careful:

```
$array = (array) $object;
```

does a shallow conversion ($object->innerObject = new stdClass() remains an object) and converting back and forth using json works but it's not a good idea if performance is an issue.

If you need all objects to be converted to associative arrays here is a better way to do that (code ripped from I don't remember where):

```
function toArray($obj)
{
    if (is_object($obj)) $obj = (array)$obj;
    if (is_array($obj)) {
        $new = array();
        foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
            $new[$key] = toArray($val);
        }
    } else {
        $new = $obj;
    }

    return $new;
}
```

Comment: I can't read the array resulting of an object casting: http://codepad.viper-7.com/AkX5pq Do you have any explanation about that?

Comment: I like this answer best. Andy E's recursive function essentially does the same thing, but I find this one easier to understand.

Answer (score 20):

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
```

I tried several ways to do a `foreach` with an object and THIS really is the most easy and cool workaround I have seen. Just one line :)

Comment: It works perfect only with public object attributes. Doesn't consider private ones.

Comment: Here are some explanation about use JsonSerialize function, but is not one line solution and i read about is not a good practice :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005860/php-json-encode-class-private-members. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: How to convert it back to an object?

Answer (score 18):

**Simple version:**

```
$arrayObject = new ArrayObject($object);
$array = $arrayObject->getArrayCopy();
```

**Updated recursive version:**

```
class RecursiveArrayObject extends ArrayObject
{
    function getArrayCopy()
    {
        $resultArray = parent::getArrayCopy();
        foreach($resultArray as $key => $val) {
            if (!is_object($val)) {
                continue;
            }
            $o = new RecursiveArrayObject($val);
            $resultArray[$key] = $o->getArrayCopy();
        }
        return $resultArray;
    }
}

$arrayObject = new RecursiveArrayObject($object);
$array = $arrayObject->getArrayCopy();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
 <?php
  print_r(json_decode(json_encode($response->response->docs),true));
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it with **get_object_vars** mentioned above.

Furthermore, I had to convert my object with **json_decode** and I had to iterate the array with the oldschool "for" loop (rather then for-each).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue with Andy Earnshaw's answer because I had factored this function out to a separate class within my application, "HelperFunctions", which meant the recursive call to objectToArray() failed.

I overcame this by specifying the class name within the array_map call like so:

```
public function objectToArray($object) {
    if (!is_object($object) && !is_array($object))
        return $object;
    return array_map(array("HelperFunctions", "objectToArray"), (array) $object);
}
```

I would have written this in the comments but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use array_values() method of php

Comment: You can't. “array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given”.

Answer (score -2):

```
//My Function is worked. Hope help full for you :)
      $input = [
            '1' => (object) [1,2,3],
            '2' => (object) [4,5,6,
                (object) [6,7,8,
                [9, 10, 11,
                    (object) [12, 13, 14]]]
            ],
            '3' =>[15, 16, (object)[17, 18]]
        ];

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($input);
        var_dump(toAnArray($input));

      public function toAnArray(&$input) {

        if (is_object($input)) {
            $input = get_object_vars($input);
        }
        foreach ($input as &$item) {
            if (is_object($item) || is_array($item)) {
                if (is_object($item)) {
                    $item = get_object_vars($item);
                }
                self::toAnArray($item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: your function does not return anything. there is no way it works!