# PHP json_encode class private members

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to JSON encode some objects in PHP, but I'm facing a problem: I want to encode data which is kept by a class private members.
I found this piece of code to encode this object by calling an encode function like:

```
public function encodeJSON() 
{ 
    foreach ($this as $key => $value) 
    { 
        $json->$key = $value; 
    } 
    return json_encode($json); 
}
```

However, this only works if the object I want to encode does not contain other objects inside, which is the case. How can I do to encode not only the "outer" object, but encode as well any members that are objects too?

Comment: either use public methods or use reflection

Answer (score 119):

The best method to serialize an object with private properties is to implement the \JsonSerializable interface and then implement your own JsonSerialize method to return the data you require to be serialized.

```
<?php

class Item implements \JsonSerializable
{
    private $var;
    private $var1;
    private $var2;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        $vars = get_object_vars($this);

        return $vars;
    }
}
```

`json_encode` will now serialize your object correctly.

Answer (score 39):

If you're using php 5.4 you can use the JsonSerializable interface: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php

You just implement a jsonSerialize method in your class which returns whatever you want to be encoded.

Then when you pass your object into json_encode, it'll encode the result of jsonSerialize.

Answer (score 15):

Anyway. You need create public method in your class to return all their fields json encoded

```
public function getJSONEncode() {
    return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
}
```

Comment: Does this work if some of the fields in turn have private variables? I would guess it doesn't, since json_encode can't be called recursively on them.

Comment: Example code in http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php seems to show it works if the method is declared in the class, as it has access to its members.

Answer (score 15):

I think @Petah's got the best approach, but that way you lose properties that are array or object. So I added a function wich do that recursively:

```
function json_encode_private($object) {

    function extract_props($object) {
        $public = [];

        $reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($object));

        foreach ($reflection->getProperties() as $property) {
            $property->setAccessible(true);

            $value = $property->getValue($object);
            $name = $property->getName();

            if(is_array($value)) {
                $public[$name] = [];

                foreach ($value as $item) {
                    if (is_object($item)) {
                        $itemArray = extract_props($item);
                        $public[$name][] = $itemArray;
                    } else {
                        $public[$name][] = $item;
                    }
                }
            } else if(is_object($value)) {
                $public[$name] = extract_props($value);
            } else $public[$name] = $value;
        }

        return $public;
    }

    return json_encode(extract_props($object));
}
```

**EDIT:** Added is_object() check inside the array loop to avoid a get_class() exception in the next extract_props() call when the array elements are not objects, like strings or numbers.

Comment: Very useful to test/debug heavily nested objects. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This is the first answer that I found for objects that have properties as nested objects. This also works for PHP 5.3.3. Thanks. +1

Comment: to also cover values that are arrays, you need an additional wrapper:

private static function extract_props_obj_or_array($objectOrArray) {
 
  if (is_array($objectOrArray)) {
   $result = array();
   foreach ($objectOrArray as $object) {
    $result[] = extract_props($object);
   }
   return $result;
    
  } else {
                        // we now know this is not an array....
   return extract_props_object($objectOrArray);
  }
 
 }

Comment: I implemented this function in my [PHP console_log debug method for WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265780/how-to-print-to-console-from-a-php-file-in-wordpress/67449528#67449528).

Comment: There is an issue in the implementation I discovered. You have to check `isset( get_class( $object ), $name )` before calling `$prop->getValue()` or you get a PHP notice, if the property is unset.

Answer (score 6):

I think this may be a great case for the Usage of Traits

using the below guist I  implemented [jsonSerializable interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) in multiple points of my app while keeping the code manageable

https://gist.github.com/zburgermeiszter/7dc5e65b06bb34a325a0363726fd8e14

```
trait JsonSerializeTrait
{
    function jsonSerialize()
    {
        $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($this);
        $props   = $reflect->getProperties(\ReflectionProperty::IS_STATIC | \ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC | \ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED | \ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE);

        $propsIterator = function() use ($props) {
            foreach ($props as $prop) {
                yield $prop->getName() => $this->{$prop->getName()};
            }
        };

        return iterator_to_array($propsIterator());
    }
}
```

then you just have to do

```
class YourClass implements JsonSerializable 
{
    use JsonSerializeTrait;

    ... normal encapsulated code...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    $objectArray = [];
    foreach($this as $key => $value) {
        $objectArray[$key] = $value;
    }

    return json_encode($objectArray);
}
```

I personally think this is a way of doing it. It is similar to Petah's, except It keeps in line with encapsulation well, because the array is populated from the object.

Put this function in either your object or as a trait to be used by your object. To each their own though.

Comment: No point doing this - Oleg's answer above works fine if you need to get private vars.

Answer (score 2):

This would print a JSON with all of the properties (public, private and protected) of class `foo`:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$properties = $reflection->getdefaultProperties();

echo json_encode($properties);
```

It would work from any context.

Answer (score 2):

Using reflection you can `json_encode` private properties, although its not considered best practice:

```
function json_encode_private($object) {
    $public = [];
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($object);
    foreach ($reflection->getProperties() as $property) {
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        $public[$property->getName()] = $property->getValue($object);
    }
    return json_encode($public);
}
```

E.g.

```
class Foo {
    public $a = 1;
    public $b = 2;
}
class Bar {
    private $c = 3;
    private $d = 4;
}

var_dump(json_encode(new Foo()));
var_dump(json_encode_private(new Bar()));
```

Outputs:

```
string(13) "{"a":1,"b":2}"
string(13) "{"c":3,"d":4}"
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/nCcKYW

Comment: Interesting approach but be aware that the provided code only works on 1st level, for nested walking it would have to be adjusted more. Also modern note - since PHP8.1 setAccessible has no effect (reflected props are now accessible by default)

Answer (score 1):

You can only encode an object's private members from within the class.  As a side note though, does the json_enocde function not work for you? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Yes, from within a class context it works. However, how should I proceed when some class members are also objects with its private members as well?