# PHP array with objects to json string

Tags: php, xml, arrays, json, object

I would like to convert an object 'Resonse' that contains an array with objects to a JSON string.

Example of the data structure:

```
$response = new model_ObjectReponse();
$error1 = new model_Message('error', 'test error 1');
$error2 = new model_Message('error', 'test error 2');
$error3 = new model_Message('error', 'test error 3');
$response->add($error1);
$response->add($error2);
$response->add($error3);
$output = json_encode($response);
print $output;
```

The message objects have the private properties type and message with getters and setters.

So does anybody know how to convert this to a json string? Btw, I have the same question for converting it to XML.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: See this discussion (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005860/php-json-encode-class-private-members) for more details and options.

Comment: What is the current return value of `json_encode($response)`?

Answer (score 0):

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

This method will allow you to save object as string. You can also unserialize object, anyway storing objects as string is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your Response object to an associative array and pass that array on to `json_encode()`. Something like this:

```
foreach ($response->getMessages() as $message)
  $responseArray['messages'][] = array(
    'type' => $message->getType(),
    'message' => $message->getMessage()
  );

json_encode($responseArray);
```

For the XML conversion, I wrote a simple class that can convert the `$response` array produced by the code above to a DOMDocument object or an XML string. You can find it here: [code.google.com/p/array-to-domdocument/](http://code.google.com/p/array-to-domdocument/)

Answer (score 0):

Your class definition could be the problem here. If you have private variables defined, a simple json_encode won't any usable output. You can created functions within your object to return a json-encoded string.