# how can i split an instance of my packet class into chunks and send them with socket_sendto function?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, packet, sendto

I have packet like this

```
    class Packet {
            private $DATASize;
            private $signature;
            private $version;
            private $HSIZE;
            private $SessionIDUser1;
            private $SessionIDUser2;
           }
```

I'm using UDP protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no methods in this class, you can encode the instance with `json_encode` and send him as a string. on the client side just decode and clone. it can be done also when the class have methods, with more complication.

Example:

```
//server
$p = new Packet;
socket_sendto($sock, json_encode($p), strlen($p), 0, $ip, $port);

//client
socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, $size, 0, $ip, $port);
$p = clone json_decode($bof); //class without methods
$p = new Packet;
$p->setAs(json_decode($bof) ); //class with methods: implement this method too.
```

**Edit:**

Now i see that your fields are `private`, so you need implement method for json encoding. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005915/2075420 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9942303/2075420.