# Cast a class instance (object) to associative array creates strange keys

Tags: php, json, class, casting, protected

I have a class with `protected` variables

```
class MyClass {
  protected $moo;
  protected $foo;
}
```

so when I try to encode an instance to json the result omits the `protected` vars.

Because of that I first use

```
$arr =  (array) $instance;
```

but than the keys are strange
`*moo`, `*foo` and I have to

```
join(explode('\u0000*\u0000',json_encode($arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)));
```

Any suggestion how to avoid these strange symbols in the first place?

Comment: Can you change your class definition?

Comment: how's you created `$instance`? and what's the output of `var_dump($arr);` after this line `$arr =  (array) $instance;`?

Comment: Thats because the properties are `protected`

Comment: If you can modify your class `myClass` I advise you to add `JsonSerializable` implementation to it.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005860/php-json-encode-class-private-members