# Incomplete array of data from Twig to Js

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I want to access an array of data from my twig in my javascript but it never gets the full array.

I have a controller that returns an array of objects that I'm using in my twig, here is an example of the objects stored :
[image]

Now, I want to access it in my javascript, I tried a lot of things but ended up with using data in my div :  (following that https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/server-data.html?fbclid=IwAR2BHWMl-OJSytkfbNgaNUFRefC85bTPw63ymvuC9Q4zPlKxZZoKZ7dvH9E)

```
<div class="table_congesService" data-conges-service="{{congesService|json_encode|e('html_attr') }}">
```

And

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var tableCongesService = document.querySelector('.table_congesService');
    var listCongesService = tableCongesService.dataset.congesService;
    console.log(listCongesService);
  });
</script>
```

However, instead of having the full structure, I only have the id when I'm displaying the result with the console.log:
[image]
What am I missing? I'm new to web and can't find what is wrong. Does it have something with the structure of my data before the encode? Or an option that I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the properties of the objects are private, except `id_conge`. That is why `json_encode` encodes only the public property `id_conge`.

You can serialize an object with private properties by implementing the `\JsonSerializable` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20117815/6192122) or export the object as array with all the properties you need in JS.