# data coming up as an empty object in this Laravel request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a route that looks like the following my `routes/api.php` file for a Laravel 8 project:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    Log::debug("request user: {$request->user()}");
    return ['data' => $request->user()];
});
```

In my log file, I clearly see `$request->user()` returning an authenticated user. Meaning, `$request->user()` is not null and has an Eloquent object coming back from the database.

The body of my response, however, says otherwise:

```
{
    "data": {}
}
```

Is there some gotchya in Laravel 8 that I'm overlooking? Why is the value for `data` an empty object when `$request->user()` contains an authenticated user?

The output from the log is a standard user object:

```
{"id":46,"name":"Amanada Name","family_name":"Name","given_name":"Amanda","phone_number":null,"email":"foo@bar.net","sub":"facebook|12341234121","remember_token":null,"created_at":"2021-01-02 23:46:00","updated_at":"2021-01-02 23:46:00"}
```

Comment: Could you please share the output of your log?

Comment: What does `Auth::guard('api')->user()` give you?

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG Posted the output of the object in the log

Comment: @Tpojka Same results as `$request->user()`

Comment: Which means? `null` or object?

Comment: @Tpojka It comes up as an empty object in the JSON output, in the log, it's completely there as expected.

Comment: Seems like first time used `$request->user()` is giving right result. What happens if you assign it to local variable before log then use variable in log and return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226776/discussion-between-randombits-and-tpojka).

Answer (score 0):

Solution found: [PHP json_encode class private members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005860/php-json-encode-class-private-members/20252122#20252122))

The problem is `json_encode`, which Laravel uses underneath the hood when converting the PHP Array to JSON, does not encode the class members. I created a [User Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#generating-resources) and updated the route to return the following:

`return response()->json(['data' => new UserResource($request->user())], 200);`

Comment: Api resources are always good choice to be made. Good practice regarding laravel can be found [here](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices).