# How to convert from object to array

Tags: php

I have an object that I need to convert to an array, how can I do this?

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
              ...
```

Comment: Not just a dupe, a SUPER dupe, identical question found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476876/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-an-array

Comment: You missed your calling... you should have been a cop.

Comment: you should really do some research before asking basic questions, which already have good answers. Typing your question title into google actually brings up the result that @EricLeschinski pointed you to. There are 4 answers to that question. One of which has 78 upvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast your object to an array:

```
$array[0] = (array) $array[0];
```

This is obviously not taking into account any more details than what you posted :P

Comment: Thank you Joseph. I'll accept this as the answer. It works.