# Looping over array returned from Google Anaylitics GAPI class in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, google-analytics-api

I'm having the following array returned from the google anaylitics gapi class in PHP as below. what is the best way to loop over this array and echo out the data?

I was thinking I could use a foreach like below but it's coming up blank. This is probably an easy thing to do but I'm struggling to get my brain in gear. I think the problem might be to do with the returned data from the gapi class is an object rather than just an array?

```
foreach($results as $result) {

 echo 'Goalresults 1:'. $result->metrics->goal1Completions;
 echo 'Goalresults 2:'. $result->metrics->goal2Completions;

}
```

This does not work either:

```
foreach($results as $result) {

 echo 'Goalresults 1:'. $result[metrics][goal1Completions];
 echo 'Goalresults 2:'. $result[metrics][goal2Completions];

}
```

but gives the error  Fatal error: Cannot use object of type gapiReportEntry as array in goals.php

Array:

```
Array
(
[0] => gapiReportEntry Object
    (
        [metrics] => Array
            (
                [goal1Completions] => 7
                [goal2Completions] => 18
            )

        [dimensions] => Array
            (
                [hour] => 01
                [date] => 20131113
            )

    )

[1] => gapiReportEntry Object
    (
        [metrics] => Array
            (
                [goal1Completions] => 32
                [goal2Completions] => 27
            )

        [dimensions] => Array
            (
                [hour] => 00
                [date] => 20131113
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: `metrics` is an array, but you are trying to access properties of it as if it was an object …

Comment: When I try to access as an array I get the error message: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type gapiReportEntry as array in goals.php

Comment: `gapiReportEntry` _is_ an object, `metrics` is not …

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it by using this function to turn the gapiReportEntry Object into an array.

```
function objectToArray( $object ) {
    if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) ) {
        return $object;
    }
    if( is_object( $object ) ) {
        $object = (array) $object;
    }
    return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );
}
```

This is from here: [How do I convert an object to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476876/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-an-array)