# php foreach with array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

The array prints out like this:

```
object(Postmaster_Rates)#2 (1) { ["_values:protected"]=> array(3) { ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["charge"]=> int(580) ["service"]=> string(6) "GROUND" } }
```

How would I display this in a "nicer" form using foreach in php.

I tried this: (but it didn't echo out anything.)

```
foreach($result as $rate){
  echo $rate['service'];
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can access ["_values:protected"] since the object is protected

Comment: okay... so what's the point of the api then, if you can't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an array of "objects" you call it like
`echo $rate->service`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use foreach? You could also try:
    $array =  (array) $yourObject;

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this at these two options.

```
// Cast to an array
$array = (array) $object;

// get_object_vars
$array = get_object_vars($object);
```

There are several answers here that can show you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2476954/330987