# Parsing error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, codeigniter, parsing, templates

I'm using twitter api to retrieve fav tweets, then parse them using a template:

```
$favs_list = $this->connection->get('favorites/list');
$data_to_parse['fav_list'] = $fav_list;
$html = $this->parser->parse('templates/tweet_list', $data_to_parse, TRUE);
$output['html'] = $html;
$this->load->view('read', $output);
```

the template `tweet_list` is simply:

```
<h3>Favs:</h3>
{fav_list}
<h5>{text}</h5>
{/fav_list}
```

But I keep getting these two error, and repeated multiple times:

> ```
> A PHP Error was encountered    
> Severity: 4096     
> Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string     
> Filename: libraries/Parser.php
> Line Number: 143
>
> A PHP Error was encountered   
> Severity: Notice     
> Message: Object of class stdClass to string conversion     
> Filename: libraries/Parser.php    
> Line Number: 143
> ```

The weird thing is that, under these errors, my html is shown in correct format.
Any idea on what caused this?

Comment: I think $favs_list is standard object array and you much get it converted to simple array and you are done.

Comment: @RakeshSharma $html id the basically my template `tweet_list` after parsing it. See: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html

Comment: @TheMohanAhuja How to do that?

Comment: I don't know optimal method but I do usually with 
json_encode(json_decode ($favs_list, true));

Comment: @TheMohanAhuja I got an error saying: `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`. I'm guessing `$favs_list` is an array after all.

Comment: sorry my mistake try this please json_decode(json_encode ($favs_list), true);

Comment: i dont know your structure of this stdClass Object, but you also can do thinks like this (array)$stdClassValue ... this will also do this encode / decode job from your json functions ;)

Comment: @TheMohanAhuja This works perfectly. Although I chose to use [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11577501/543711). Please post an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know optimal method but I do usually with

```
json_decode(json_encode ($favs_list), true);
```

Comment: just curious, just how do u know this?

Comment: @Conan When I get data from mysql, I usually get data in object format, that I skip using this me way only. That's how I know this.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print out `favs_list` but the content is an object, and its having a hard time trying to convert that object.

Just convert the object to an array instead and use accordingly

`$array = (array) $object;`

in your case

```
$favs_list = $this->connection->get('favorites/list');
$data_to_parse['fav_list'] = (array) $fav_list;
```