# Object property's value is an array. Getting notice/warning saying otherwise

Tags: php, arrays, object, warnings, notice

I'm getting a **Notice** and a **Warning** here, not an error. My code still works. Just wanted to see if someone could figure out *why* I'm getting the notice and warning.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in file.php on line 152

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given file.php on line 152
```

Line 152 is an if() statement:

```
if($user->type == 'x' && in_array($user->email, $campaign->settings->email_list))
{ do stuff }
```

I've pinpointed the issue to the `$campaign` object. Using print_r on $campaign outputs quite a bit of info, but this is the important part:

```
Campaign Object
{
    [settings] => stdClass Object
        (
            [email_list] => Array
                (
                    [0] => support@domain.com
                    [1] => customer@domain.com
                )
        )
}
```

Obviously, $campaign->settings->email_list is an array. Why am I getting the Notice and Warning, then? `$campaign` is created directly above Line 152.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may get this notice because of possible uninitialization (maybe `null` value) assigned to `$campaign->settings` campaign's internal object. 
Please ensure with a `var_dump($campaign->settings)` what is the real value of the property before the line with `in_array` function.

Comment: Should have included that in my original post, but I already did that. `var_dump($campaign->settings)` outputs `object(stdClass)#14 (7) { ["email_list"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(19) "support@domain.com" [1]=> string(19) "customer@domain.com" }" }

Comment: Sorry, you wrote you used print_r. Nevertheless the *Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in file.php on line 152* points in that direction. This is strange :)

Answer (score 0):

try this some time it will works.

```
$campaign['settings']['email_list']
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! That would only work if `$campaign` was an Array, and its `settings` element was an Array. Since I'm dealing with objects, this particular solution doesn't apply.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476876/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-an-array
check this link you will get an idea