# JQuery Serialized array to PHP array Nesttable jscript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, serialization, jquery-nestable

I found the following code online. And I would love to use it in my own projects.

http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/

This draggable jquery generated tree structure generates a serialized array.
To for what seems to me this is a serialized javascript array.

```
[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":3}]},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":4},{"id":9,"children":[{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8}]}]}]},{"id":11},{"id":12,"children":[{"id":10}]}]
```

For what I could find I should use **parse_str** and that should do it.

But to no avail.
The array generated is empty.

I tried the following test code :

```
   <?php

    $Str = '[{"id":1},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8}]},{"id":9},{"id":10}]},{"id":11},{"id":12}]';

    parse_str($Str, $values);

    print_r($values);

    ?>
```

I hope that anyone sees what I am overlooking.

Thanks in advance!

> **Answer!**
>
> What I have overlooked is that this is not a Javascript Serialized
>   array but rather a JSON encoded string.
>
> As suggested below I should use JSON decode.
>
> ```
> $Str = json_decode('[{"id":1},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8}]},{"id":9},{"id":10}]},{"id":11},{"id":12}]');
> ```
>
> This will deliver the result as shown below.
>
> IF I want to use the result as an array instead of what supplied I
>   should use the following function to convert the objects to a valid
>   array:
>
> ```
> function toArray($obj){
>     if (is_object($obj)) $obj = (array)$obj;
>     if (is_array($obj)) {
>         $new = array();
>         foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
>             $new[$key] = toArray($val);
>         }
>     } else {
>         $new = $obj;
>     }
>
>     return $new;
> }
>
> $Str = toArray($Str);
> ```
>
> (* this I copied from :
>   [How do I convert an object to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476876/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-an-array)
>   *)

Comment: don't use like that. it will not follow standards for json parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you should use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) like this

```
<?php

    $Str = '[{"id":1},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8}]},{"id":9},{"id":10}]},{"id":11},{"id":12}]';

    $php_array = json_decode($Str);

    // and just in case there is an error while decoding
    if ( json_last_error() > 0 ) {
        echo json_last_error_msg();
    }

    print_r($php_array);

?>
```

Which will generate the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 6
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7
                                        )

                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 8
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                        )

                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 11
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12
        )

)
```

Or if you want the whole dataset returned as an array rather than the objects that exist in the original data you can add the second parameter to `json_decode($Str, true)` and it will all be in arrays:

```
<?php

    $Str = '[{"id":1},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8}]},{"id":9},{"id":10}]},{"id":11},{"id":12}]';

    $php_array = json_decode($Str, true);

    // and just in case there is an error while decoding
    if ( json_last_error() > 0 ) {
        echo json_last_error_msg();
    }

    print_r($php_array);

?>
```

Giving this result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 6
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 8
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
        )

)
```

Comment: How do I convert this into a normal array? I could write a function to do this. But is there any readily available code to do this?

Comment: The json_decode does just that, look at the output? Or what do you mean by a **normal array**

Comment: Does the existance of class objects in the result bother you?

Comment: Well If I try to use the result as an array I get:

( ! ) Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\test\draggable_tree\simple\test2.php on line 8

Comment: So also you need to learn how to address an array of objects i.e. `$phpArray[1]->childern[2]->id` or use the second parameter to make it all an array

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `json_decode`

```
print_r(json_decode($Str, true));
```