# How to fetch array from nested object in php?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I am getting this while `print_r()`.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Ramesh
            [cdate] => 2015-10-03 10:36:08
            [private] => 0
            [userid] => 1
            [subscriber_count] => 0
        )

    [result_code] => 1
    [result_message] => Success: Something is returned
    [result_output] => json
    [http_code] => 200
    [success] => 1
)
```

I have tried lot but no use. please help me

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: _`I have tried lot but no use`_ But for what you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an object to an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476876/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-an-array)

Comment: where is the array() ?

Comment: I have tried all the possibilities , Nothing works. I have marked right answer below. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use  `get_object_vars()`  this may help.

Comment: then mark it as answered so that if anyone is searching will get it easily .

Comment: Yeah. Site does not allowed me to mark it as answer for sometime. that's why the delay took place.

Comment: not a problem, your problem is solved , that was the first and fundamental need of this post.