# Access Array element: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel-5.1

I have an object (`$project`) in Blade.

When I do a `{{ var_dump($project) }}` I get:

```
object(stdClass)[603]
  public 'image_header' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[610]
          public 'img' => string 'amsterdam.jpg' (length=13)
```

When I try to access this element in blade with:

```
{{ $project->image_header[0]->img }}
```

It keeps giving this error:

> Undefined offset: 0.

Print_r output:

```
stdClass Object ( 
           [image_header] => Array ( 
                             [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                                       [img] => amsterdam.jpg 
                                    ) 
                             ) 
                 )
```

Comment: Can you use print_r()?

Comment: Ofcourse I can. Updated!

Comment: Your code is correct. Hmm. Can you try `{!! $project->image_header[0]->img !!}`?

Comment: I already did that: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Answer (score 0):

```
//recreating your original
$obj2 = (object)['img' => 'amsterdam.jpg'];
$obj1 = (object)['image_header' => [$obj2]];

$answer = json_decode(json_encode($obj1), true)['image_header'][0]['img'];

var_dump($answer); //string(13) "amsterdam.jpg"
```

From [stackoverflow back in 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476876/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-an-array) (requires PHP >= 5.2 for native json and 5.? to get the elements from the function call, else split into two lines)