# How to convert array object into simple array format

Tags: php, arrays

Simply , how to remove object from this array . How to convert into array.......

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#44 (8) {
    ["invoice"]=>
    string(2) "32"
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-03-04 03:40:53"
    ["type_ext"]=>
    string(6) "SUBSCR"
    ["type_not"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#42 (8) {
    ["id_invoice"]=>
    string(2) "32"
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-03-04 03:40:53"
    ["type_ext"]=>
    string(6) "SUBSCR"
    ["type_not"]=>
    int(4)
  }
}
```

explain it simply...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array?rq=1 - Did you even try to search? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476876/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-an-array from just copying your title and googling it.

Comment: there are lot of question asked u search before asking a question

Comment: @Muhammad Please read how to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete an element from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

This question is already asked multiple times. 
Anyway, the simplest solution is to use built-in `json` functions

```
json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
```

[How do I convert an object to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476876/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-an-array)

[Convert PHP object to associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)