# Echo element from array with dynamic value

Tags: php, arrays, decode

```
{  
"something":"not important;",
"something2":"less important",
"something3":"inexistent",
"something4":"nothing",
"something5":{  
        "1232":{  // this value is dynamic
        "NeedToEchoThis":1230,
        "NeedToEchoThis2":"12343",
        "NeedToEchoThis3":22222,
  }
},
  "something6":"else",
"something7":"0"
}
```

When using json_decode, I get that array. But... how to echo the values within "something5" since it has a dynamic value right next to it? I tried using

> $var1 = $obj->something5[0]->NeedToEchoThis;

But... still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: `$var1 = $obj->something5[0]->1232->NeedToEchoThis` And echo will throw an error because inside is still an array. So use `print_r()`

Comment: Well besides that your json isn't fully valid, you want to look at `array_search()`.

Comment: @aldrin27 that's a dynamic value and it changes everytime...

Comment: Try this: 

$key = array_keys( $obj->something5[0] )[0];

$var1 = $obj->something5[0]->{$key}->NeedToEchoThis;

Comment: @Karlos thanks, but Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in...

Comment: Ok, it is an object, cast it in an array: 
$key = array_keys( (array) $obj->something5[0] )[0]; 
$var1 = $obj->something5[0]->{$key}->NeedToEchoThis;

Comment: @Karlos using this code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11577501/6122403 I managed to cast it but now I get this: Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in...

Comment: So, which key(s) are dynamic? Only "1232"? Or is "NeedToEchoThis" als dynamic/unknown?

Comment: It means that case the array was empty, a good solution could be to check if the array is not empty. I post a solution.

Comment: @VolkerK left column static, right column dynamic. "1232" is dynamic as well.

Comment: left column? right column? No idea what you mean.

Comment: @VolkerK "something" (left) "not important". (right)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. But maybe I'm just not meant to....

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. iterate over the array `something5` with a [foreach](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(data(), true);

foreach( $data['something5'] as $k=>$v) {
    if ( isset($v['NeedToEchoThis']) ) {
        echo $k, ' -> NeedToEchoThis => ', $v['NeedToEchoThis'], "\r\n";
    }
}



function data() {
    return <<< eoj
{
    "something": "not important;",
    "something2": "less important",
    "something3": "inexistent",
    "something4": "nothing",
    "something5": {
        "1232": {
            "NeedToEchoThis": "1230",
            "NeedToEchoThis2": "12343",
            "NeedToEchoThis3": "22222"
        }
    },
    "something6": "else",
    "something7": "0"
}
eoj;
}
```

prints

```
1232 -> NeedToEchoThis => 1230
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works just fine but how to make to get the array from an url?

Comment: Again: Whaaat? Array from url? What...do...you...mean? Wild guess: you want to request the json "document" from a url? Like e.g. `$data = json_decode('http://foo.bar/getjson.php', true);`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you use json_decode.

When you json_decode($input) you get an object (not an array) that contains other objects.

```
$obj = json_decode($input);
echo $obj->something5->{'1232'}->NeedToEchoThis;
```

Or:

```
$obj = json_decode($input, true);
echo $obj['something5'][1232]['NeedToEchoThis'];
```

Here is a complete runnable example:

```
$input = <<<EEE
{  
"something":"not important;",
"something2":"less important",
"something3":"inexistent",
"something4":"nothing",
"something5":{  
    "1232":{  
        "NeedToEchoThis":1230,
        "NeedToEchoThis2":"12343",
        "NeedToEchoThis3":22222
    }
},
  "something6":"else",
  "something7":"0"
}
EEE;
echo $input . "\n";
$obj = json_decode($input);
var_dump($obj);

echo $obj->something5->{'1232'}->NeedToEchoThis;
echo "\n";

// If you don't know the key names:

$vars = get_object_vars ( $obj );
foreach($vars as $name => $value ) {
    if ( is_object($value) ) {
        echo "$name => "; print_r($value);
    } elseif( is_string($value) ){
        echo "$name => $value\n";        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mention dynamic value it's not really clear what you mean. The notation in your json example is not clear also.

In case the "1232" value changes, you could get the dynamic value of the element as follows:

```
if( !empty($obj->something5) ) { 
    $arr = (array) $obj->something5[0];
    if( is_array($arr) && !empty($arr) ) {
        $key = array_keys( $arr )[0];
        $var1 = $obj->something5[0]->{$key}->NeedToEchoThis;
    } else {
        $var1 = "nothing to show";
    }

} else { 
    $var1 = "nothing to show";
}
```