# How to convert object of stdClass to array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am getting the next error when trying to display a view in Laravel :

> "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\resources\views\cms\contactus.blade.php)".

My Controller:

```
public function contactus(){ 

    ContactUS::get_content(self::$data);
    return view('cms.contactus', self::$data); 

}
```

My Model:

```
class ContactUS extends Model
{

public $table = 'contactus';

public $fillable = ['name','email','message']; 

static public function get_content(&$data){ 


        $sql = "SELECT cu.*,name,email,message FROM contactus cu "
            . "ORDER BY cu.created_at DESC ";

        $data['contactusd'] = DB::select($sql); 

     }

}
```

My view:

```
@extends ('cms.cms_master') 
@section('cms_content')
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
    <h1 class="page-header">Contact us form information</h1>
    @if($contactusd) 
    <br><br>
    <table class="table table-bordered">  
        <thead>
            <tr>  
                <th>Name</th> 
                <th>Email</th> 
                <th>Message</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead> 
        @foreach($contactusd as $item)  
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $item['name']}}</td> 
            <td>
                <ul>

                    <li> Email: {{ $item['email']}}, Massage: {{$item['message'] }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </td> 
            <td>{{ $item[created_at]}}</td> 
        </tr>

    </table> 
    @else 
    <p style="font-size: 18px">No information...</p>
    @endif
</div> 

@endsection
```

Comment: Well, you can use it as an object instead (`$item->email`), or convert it to an array `@foreach($contactusd as (array)$item)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an object to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476876/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-an-array)

Comment: nah he is asking for laravel and however you should prefer eloquent instead of Raw Queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have hell lot of mistake in your blade file

```
@if($contactusd) 
    <br><br>
    <table class="table table-bordered">  
        <thead>
            <tr>  
                <th>Name</th> 
                <th>Email</th> 
                <th>Message</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead> 
        @foreach($contactusd as $item)  
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $item->name }}</td> 
            <td>
                <ul>

                    <li> Email: {{ $item->email}}, Massage: {{$item->message }}</li>

                </ul>
            </td> 
            <td>{{ $item->created_at}}</td> 
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table> 
    @else 
    <p style="font-size: 18px">No information...</p>
    @endif
```

or

```
$contactusd = ContactUS::get_content(self::$data)->toArray();
return view('cms.contactus', $contactusd);
```

Answer (score 7):

To convert an object to array (as is your question) use `$array = (array) $object;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$sql = "SELECT cu.*,name,email,message FROM contactus cu "
            . "ORDER BY cu.created_at DESC ";

$data['contactusd'] = DB::select($sql)->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you getting data is in std class ,
you can write like this in view page `{{ $item->name }}`

If you getting data is in **std class** ,
you can write like this in view page `{{$item['message']}}`

backside write like this

```
$sql = "SELECT cu.*,name,email,message FROM contactus cu "
            . "ORDER BY cu.created_at DESC ";

$data['contactusd'] = DB::select($sql)->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
$data = ContactUS::get_content(self::$data)->toArray();
return view('cms.contactus', $data);
```