# Displaying product in a row with three products laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I wrote the following code to display some `products` on a page but all that I want is to display only `3` items in a row.

My code for displaying all products (i have to display more than 15 products):

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($products as $item)
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
                <div class="blog-item item swin-transition">
                    <div class="block-img">
                        <img style="width: 269.844px;height: 254.984px " src="{{url('images/product/'.$item['image'])}}" alt="" class="img img-responsive">
                        <div class="group-btn">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="swin-btn btn-link" tabindex="0"><i class="icons fa fa-link"></i></a>
                            <a href="javascript:addCart({{ $item['id'] }});" class="swin-btn btn-add-to-card" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block-content">
                        <h6 class="title" style="font-size: 15px">
                            <a href="/product/single/{{$item['id']}}" tabindex="0">{{$item['name_'.$lang]}}</a>
                        </h6>
                        <div class="product-info">
                            <ul class="list-inline">
                                <li class="author">
                                   <span>{{Lang::get('frontend.price')}}:</span>
                                   <span class="text">{{number_format($item['online_price'])}} {{Lang::get('frontend.unit')}}</span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="rating">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="0">
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want only 3 item then why no change `foreach($products as $item)` to `for` loop?

Comment: How can i change for loop as well?

Comment: Do you want to display 3 item in each row or only 3 row with 1 item each?

Comment: Surely 3 item in each row ,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    php `array_chunk()` function will serve your purpose [http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php][1]

    <div class="products">
        @foreach(array_chunk($products,3,true) as $chunk)
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($chunk as $item)
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
                <div class="blog-item item swin-transition">
                    <div class="block-img">
                        <img style="width: 269.844px;height: 254.984px " src="{{url('images/product/'.$item['image'])}}" alt="" class="img img-responsive">
                        <div class="group-btn">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="swin-btn btn-link" tabindex="0"><i class="icons fa fa-link"></i></a>
                            <a href="javascript:addCart({{ $item['id'] }});" class="swin-btn btn-add-to-card" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block-content">
                        <h6 class="title" style="font-size: 15px"><a href="/product/single/{{$item['id']}}" tabindex="0">{{$item['name_'.$lang]}}</a></h6>
                        <div class="product-info">
                            <ul class="list-inline">
                                <li class="author"><span>{{Lang::get('frontend.price')}}:</span><span class="text">{{number_format($item['online_price'])}} {{Lang::get('frontend.unit')}}</span></li>
                                <li class="rating"><a href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        @endforeach;
    </div>



  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php
```

Comment: it's a good idea. but my `$products` is belong to Object ,not array. how can i ?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476876/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-an-array