# PHP: Accessing array inside object in another array from WSDL

Tags: php, api, wsdl

I am trying to access photos held in a result from a WSDL api that is accessed using the PHP SoapClient.  I need to list all photo URLs in the ImageItems of the MultimediaDescriptions with the [DimensionCategory]  of "Original".  The format is below.

I can connect to the WSDL fine and access the unit array via $result->UnitInfo->Descriptions->MultimediaDescriptions->MultimediaDescription.  However, I am struggling to work my way down to get a list of the image URLs.  I keep getting errors along the lines of "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

```
stdClass Object
(
[UnitInfo] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Descriptions] => stdClass Object
            (
                [MultimediaDescriptions] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [MultimediaDescription] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [ImageItems] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [ImageItem] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [ImageFormat] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/3417200176.jpeg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 640
                                                                                [Height] => 425
                                                                                [Title] => -Original
                                                                                [FileName] => 3417200176.jpeg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Original
                                                                            )

                                                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/1681940176.jpg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 100
                                                                                [Height] => 71
                                                                                [Title] => -Thumbnail
                                                                                [FileName] => 1681940176.jpg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Thumbnail
                                                                            )

                                                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/4190190176.jpg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 350
                                                                                [Height] => 250
                                                                                [Title] => -Standard
                                                                                [FileName] => 4190190176.jpg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Standard
                                                                            )

                                                                        [3] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/9730080176.jpg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 300
                                                                                [Height] => 214
                                                                                [Title] => -Descriptive
                                                                                [FileName] => 9730080176.jpg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Descriptive
                                                                            )

                                                                        [4] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/1399320176.jpg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 640
                                                                                [Height] => 457
                                                                                [Title] => -Large
                                                                                [FileName] => 1399320176.jpg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Large
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [Description] => stdClass Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [_] => 
                                                                        [Caption] => 
                                                                    )

                                                                [Category] => Exterior
                                                                [Removal] => 
                                                                [IsDefault] => 1
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [ImageFormat] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/0875930328.jpeg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 1024
                                                                                [Height] => 768
                                                                                [Title] => -Original
                                                                                [FileName] => 0875930328.jpeg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Original
                                                                            )

                                                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/1300260328.jpg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 100
                                                                                [Height] => 71
                                                                                [Title] => -Thumbnail
                                                                                [FileName] => 1300260328.jpg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Thumbnail
                                                                            )

                                                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/5236970328.jpg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 350
                                                                                [Height] => 250
                                                                                [Title] => -Standard
                                                                                [FileName] => 5236970328.jpg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Standard
                                                                            )

                                                                        [3] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/5760350328.jpg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 300
                                                                                [Height] => 214
                                                                                [Title] => -Descriptive
                                                                                [FileName] => 5760350328.jpg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Descriptive
                                                                            )

                                                                        [4] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/7745220328.jpg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 640
                                                                                [Height] => 457
                                                                                [Title] => -Large
                                                                                [FileName] => 7745220328.jpg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Large
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [Description] => stdClass Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [_] => 
                                                                        [Caption] => 
                                                                    )

                                                                [Category] => Exterior
                                                                [Removal] => 
                                                                [IsDefault] => 
                                                            )

                                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [ImageFormat] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/0875930327.jpeg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 1024
                                                                                [Height] => 768
                                                                                [Title] => -Original
                                                                                [FileName] => 0875930327.jpeg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Original
                                                                            )

                                                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/0187440327.jpg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 100
                                                                                [Height] => 71
                                                                                [Title] => -Thumbnail
                                                                                [FileName] => 0187440327.jpg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Thumbnail
                                                                            )

                                                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/5760350327.jpg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 350
                                                                                [Height] => 250
                                                                                [Title] => -Standard
                                                                                [FileName] => 5760350327.jpg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Standard
                                                                            )

                                                                        [3] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/1300260327.jpg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 300
                                                                                [Height] => 214
                                                                                [Title] => -Descriptive
                                                                                [FileName] => 1300260327.jpg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Descriptive
                                                                            )

                                                                        [4] => stdClass Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [URL] => https://pictures.escapia.com/WaikoloaVR/16649/5236970327.jpg
                                                                                [UnitOfMeasureCode] => 9
                                                                                [Width] => 640
                                                                                [Height] => 457
                                                                                [Title] => -Large
                                                                                [FileName] => 5236970327.jpg
                                                                                [DimensionCategory] => Large
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [Description] => stdClass Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [_] => 
                                                                        [Caption] => 
                                                                    )

                                                                [Category] => Exterior
                                                                [Removal] => 
                                                                [IsDefault] => 
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [TextItems] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [TextItem] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [Description] => stdClass Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [_] => Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet flank commodo turducken, dolore fugiat sausage aliquip chicken cupidatat ut. Short ribs dolore chicken ground round, incididunt frankfurter meatball. Boudin reprehenderit bresaola spare ribs pork chop kielbasa. Hamburger kielbasa pancetta labore tri-tip.
                                                                    )

                                                                [Title] => Long Description
                                                                [Removal] => 
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [Description] => stdClass Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [_] => 
                                                                    )

                                                                [Title] => Driving Directions
                                                                [Removal] => 
                                                            )

                                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [Description] => stdClass Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [_] => 
                                                                    )

                                                                [Title] => Room Description
                                                                [Removal] => 
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [2] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [VideoItems] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [VideoItem] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [VideoFormat] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [URL] => <iframe width="650" height="365" src="https://my.matterport.com/show/?m=aSx1MpRRqif" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                                            )

                                                        [Removal] => 
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [DescriptiveText] => Pig velit bresaola, sirloin turkey laborum shoulder ut. T-bone labore est nostrud, dolore eiusmod prosciutto.
                [RateNotes] => 3 night minimum (always).


            )

etc....
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2476954/5260982) which will create an array from the WSDL object and make it easier to navigate.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.